# Java threading issue on VPS

Tags: memory, locking, jvm, vps

I have a VPS with Centos running with the following details:

```
[root@XXXXXXX~]# uname -a

Linux xxxxxxxx2.6.32-042stab055.10 #1 SMP Thu May 10 15:38:32 MSD 2012 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
```

I am trying to run the ecommerce system shopizer from the tomcat installed on it.
I had tried to build it on the VPS but did not succeed so I built it else where and copied the war files on the VPS's tomcat.

The issue I am facing now and during the build too was that the build was hanging when i ran the built ant scripts. now when i am launching the tomcat server whose details are as follows :

```
Server version: Apache Tomcat/6.0.35
Server built:   Nov 28 2011 11:20:06
Server number:  6.0.35.0
OS Name:        Linux
OS Version:     2.6.32-042stab055.10
Architecture:   i386
JVM Version:    1.6.0_24-b24
JVM Vendor:     Sun Microsystems Inc.
```

the server hangs up at start and when I take thread dump (both in this case and the build case) I get the following :

```
"GC Daemon" daemon prio=10 tid=0xa09fd000 nid=0x36ef in Object.wait() [0xa08f7000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0xa6c35a88> (a sun.misc.GC$LatencyLock)
    at sun.misc.GC$Daemon.run(GC.java:117)
    - locked <0xa6c35a88> (a sun.misc.GC$LatencyLock)

"Low Memory Detector" daemon prio=10 tid=0xb7686000 nid=0x36ed runnable [0x00000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C1 CompilerThread0" daemon prio=10 tid=0xb7684000 nid=0x36ec runnable [0x00000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Signal Dispatcher" daemon prio=10 tid=0xb7682800 nid=0x36eb waiting on condition [0x00000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Finalizer" daemon prio=10 tid=0xb7673000 nid=0x36ea in Object.wait() [0xa0ffe000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0xa6ad0b58> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:133)
    - locked <0xa6ad0b58> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:149)
    at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Finalizer.java:177)

"Reference Handler" daemon prio=10 tid=0xb7671800 nid=0x36e9 in Object.wait() [0xa1198000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0xa6ad0a58> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
    at java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Reference.java:133)
    - locked <0xa6ad0a58> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)

"main" prio=10 tid=0xb7605c00 nid=0x36e7 runnable [0xb775d000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.lang.Byte$ByteCache.<clinit>(Byte.java:79)
    at java.lang.Byte.valueOf(Byte.java:102)
    - waiting on <0xa6ad0a58> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
    at java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Reference.java:133)
    - locked <0xa6ad0a58> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)

"main" prio=10 tid=0xb7605c00 nid=0x36e7 runnable [0xb775d000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.lang.Byte$ByteCache.<clinit>(Byte.java:79)
    at java.lang.Byte.valueOf(Byte.java:102)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.DefaultTypeConverter.<init>(DefaultTypeConverter.java:59)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.XWorkConverter.<init>(XWorkConverter.java:186)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:532)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$ConstructorInjector.construct(ContainerImpl.java:419)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerBuilder$5.create(ContainerBuilder.java:207)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.Scope$2$1.create(Scope.java:51)
    - locked <0xa18cf408> (a com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$ParameterInjector.inject(ContainerImpl.java:462)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.getParameters(ContainerImpl.java:477)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.access$000(ContainerImpl.java:34)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$MethodInjector.inject(ContainerImpl.java:293)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$ConstructorInjector.construct(ContainerImpl.java:431)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerBuilder$5.create(ContainerBuilder.java:207)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.Scope$2$1.create(Scope.java:51)
    - locked <0xa18cf408> (a com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$ParameterInjector.inject(ContainerImpl.java:462)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.getParameters(ContainerImpl.java:477)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.access$000(ContainerImpl.java:34)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$MethodInjector.inject(ContainerImpl.java:293)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$ConstructorInjector.construct(ContainerImpl.java:431)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerBuilder$5.create(ContainerBuilder.java:207)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.Scope$2$1.create(Scope.java:51)
    - locked <0xa18cf408> (a com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$ParameterInjector.inject(ContainerImpl.java:462)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.getParameters(ContainerImpl.java:477)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.access$000(ContainerImpl.java:34)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$MethodInjector.inject(ContainerImpl.java:293)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$ConstructorInjector.construct(ContainerImpl.java:431)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerBuilder$5.create(ContainerBuilder.java:207)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.Scope$2$1.create(Scope.java:51)
    - locked <0xa18cf408> (a com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerBuilder$3.create(ContainerBuilder.java:93)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerBuilder$7.call(ContainerBuilder.java:487)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerBuilder$7.call(ContainerBuilder.java:484)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.callInContext(ContainerImpl.java:574)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerBuilder.create(ContainerBuilder.java:484)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.createBootstrapContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:252)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:193)
    - locked <0xa37c05b0> (a com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration)
....
....
..
"VM Thread" prio=10 tid=0xb766d800 nid=0x36e8 runnable 

"VM Periodic Task Thread" prio=10 tid=0xb7688400 nid=0x36ee waiting on condition 

JNI global references: 911

Heap
 def new generation   total 39424K, used 5740K [0xa1580000, 0xa4040000, 0xa6ad0000)
  eden space 35072K,  12% used [0xa1580000, 0xa19a8e88, 0xa37c0000)
  from space 4352K,  34% used [0xa37c0000, 0xa3932570, 0xa3c00000)
  to   space 4352K,   0% used [0xa3c00000, 0xa3c00000, 0xa4040000)
 tenured generation   total 87424K, used 1432K [0xa6ad0000, 0xac030000, 0xb1580000)
   the space 87424K,   1% used [0xa6ad0000, 0xa6c36038, 0xa6c36200, 0xac030000)
 compacting perm gen  total 12288K, used 11825K [0xb1580000, 0xb2180000, 0xb5580000)
   the space 12288K,  96% used [0xb1580000, 0xb210c588, 0xb210c600, 0xb2180000)
No shared spaces configured.
```

What can I do to resolve the issue or is it a bug/issue with java running on VPS??

B) the jvm sometimes crashes on the same VPS with the following error :

```
[root@xxxxxx ~]# java
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for object heap
Could not create the Java virtual machine.
[root@xxxxxx ~]# free
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:       1155072     561320     593752          0          0     317124
-/+ buffers/cache:     244196     910876
Swap:            0          0          0
```

Very strange to me, can anyone explain me this behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you try to update your operating system and your JVM.

I think this crash is due to a bug in your actual configuration.

Comment: I brought a dedicated server. VPS was having issues. The JVM and VPS threads might not be compatible.

Comment: I don't think so. I dont see any compatibility problems between jvm and vps.
vps is a virtual machine, and every virtualisation provider validates it's virtualization solution when it is compatible with c/c++ apps and jvm for sure. 
for sure there are things that i dont know. 
The most important thing that now you are enjoying yout java application.

Comment: I think the problem was that the VPS didn't offer dedicated memory and was increasing the memory on demand but by the time it could do so,the JVM was detecting low memory and crashing as you can see in the log.